# all possible length k combinations of a string in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I would like to get all possible combinations of the letters in a string with length k.  I know there are many posts on this but I have a little twist k is larger than the length of the string.

This is what I have so far, its simple and works if k <= len(string):

```
 string = 'ABCD'
 permutations = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(string, k)]
```

results if k = 4:

```
 ['ABCD', 'ABDC', 'ACBD', 'ACDB', 'ADBC', 'ADCB', 'BACD', 'BADC', 'BCAD', 'BCDA', 
'BDAC','BDCA', 'CABD', 'CADB', 'CBAD', 'CBDA', 'CDAB', 'CDBA', 'DABC', 'DACB', 
'DBAC', 'DBCA', 'DCAB', 'DCBA']
```

This works as expected.  However, I would like all possible combinations of these four letters with k > len(string).

An example answer I would like would be:

```
string = 'AB'
k = 4
result = ['AAA,'ABB','AAB', 'ABA','BBB', 'BAA'.......]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 4^15 strings of length 15 consisting of A, B, C and D. That's over **one billion** strings. Of course your computer jammed up. (Note that there are **one trillion** permutations of 15 elements, which is what you asked your computer to calculate)

Comment: You should give an example of what output you want to see.

Comment: @nneonneo: right, that way SO can be jammed up trying to process a multi-GB HTTP POST, instead of just the questioner's computer being jammed up ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm relatively sure that such a POST would fail. At least, I hope so. (sudden urge to try)

Comment: Note that `itertools.permutations` is giving you the number of well.... permutations, not combinations. Following what @nneonneo said, if you're allowing repeated letters there are m^n possible strings of length n, using m symbols. Given a string s of length n, there are n! (factorial) permutations of s. A permutation is a rearrangement that uses each of the original items once and only once.

Comment: Ok yes this is why it jammed up makes sense.  Sorry I'm very new to programming.  Another possibility would be to not store all combinations.  I'm trying to search a very large string for the number of occurrences of each combination and see which combination occurs the most often.

Comment: @Samantha: Then ask that. Don't fall into the trap of the X/Y problem. (If you actually check every single combination, your memory and CPU time will explode. There are much, much easier ways).

Comment: The example you gave with `'AB'` and `k = 4` does not follow the same logic as the one you gave with `'ABCD'` and `k = 4`. I find this misleading. I stuck with the interpretation of the latter to build my answer.

Comment: Your examples don't seem to correspond. You have `'AAA'` in the example at the end, but you don't have `'AAAA'` in the output from the `permutations` code that you say is correct.

Answer (score 9):

You may well want

```
itertools.product(string, repeat=k)
```

instead.  Try it!  Your description is ill-defined, so can't guess for sure.

Example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for p in itertools.product("ab", repeat=3):
...     print p
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'a', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'a')
('b', 'b', 'b')
```

Comment: And also be aware that you're unlikely to have enough memory to be able to make a list out of this for k=15. But that's OK, the point of `itertools` in part is to generate sequences too big for memory.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment:

> I'm trying to search a very large string for the number of occurrences of each combination and see which combination occurs the most often.

There's another way to do what you want:

```
def substrings(vlarge, k):
    return (vlarge[idx:idx+k] for idx in range(len(vlarge)-k+1))

def uses_only(value, chars):
    return all(ch in chars for ch in value)

def most_common(vlarge, chars, k):
    return collections.Counter(s for s in substrings(vlarge, k) if uses_only(s, chars)).most_common(1)
```

You can then look at making this basic idea more efficient: for example if you encounter an `'x'` character in `vlarge` then you know that none of the substrings that include it are combinations of `'abcd'`. So you can skip ahead to the substring that starts one place after the `x`:

```
def generate_substrings(vlarge, chars, k):
    idx = 0
    goodrange = 0
    while idx <= len(vlarge) - k:
        while goodrange < idx + k:
            if vlarge[goodrange] in chars:
                goodrange += 1
            else:
                idx = goodrange + 1
                if idx > len(vlarge) - k:
                    return
                goodrange = idx
        yield vlarge[idx:goodrange]
        idx += 1

def most_common(vlarge, chars, k):
    return collections.Counter(generate_substrings(vlarge, chars, k)).most_common(1)
```

Compared with this approach, the "obvious" idea (iterate over all combinations, counting how many times they appear as a substring, and keeping track of the best so far) uses less memory but will be a *lot* slower, since it has to make a *lot* of passes over the very large string.

If I have misunderstood what you mean by "combinations", that is to say if my `uses_only` function is incorrect, then you'd have to adjust my idea accordingly. The point is: count the actual substrings of the form you want, because there are fewer of them than there are hypothetical substrings of the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will only be a theoretical analysis of what you are doing.
I will denote the binomial coefficient defining the number of parts containing *k* elements of a set containing *n* elements by *C(k,n)*.

Suppose you have a string of length *n* ∈ ℕ<sup>*</sup> and *k* ∈ ℕ, *k ⩾ n*. I will assume all the characters in your string are distinct.
I understood that you are trying to build a string of *k* characters extracted from your input string.

A combination of your string characters can be seen as a permutation of ⟦*1, n*⟧. There are *n!* such permutations ...

Then, when *k > n*, things are getting much worse ... Let *r = k mod n* and *p = (k - r)/n*. Obviously we have :

> *p ⩾ 1*
>   *0 ⩽ r < p*

Your output string can there be decomposed in *p* "complete" substrings made out of a permutation of your *n* input characters and one substring made out of only *r* characters of your input string.

To build such an "incomplete" substring, you first have to choose a subset of *r* characters of your input string and then a permutation of such characters. Finally, the number *s<sub>r,n</sub>* of such possible substrings is :

> *s<sub>r,n</sub> = C(r,n).r!*

*Note that this formula won't lead to an invalid **global result** when r = 0, since C(0,n) = 1 and 0! = 1 by convention.*

The final number of *k*-long strings you can build according to your scheme is :

> *s<sub>tot</sub> = (C(r,n).r!).(n!)<sup>p</sup>*

This number is *outrageously* high !

With *k = 4* and *n = 2*, we have :

> s<sub>tot</sub> = (C(0,4).0!).(2!)<sup>2</sup> = 4

```
result = ['ABAB', 'ABBA', 'BAAB', 'BABA']
```